# Xuggler issue with MAC OS

Tags: java, macos, xuggler

I have made Screen Recorder And Player Application using Xuggler 5.4. I have developed with the Windows 8 64 bit environment . I have made it to work as WebStart project and launch (.jnlp) in MAC 10.8 64 bit . When I run it , Recorder Works fine but when I open it in the my Player it throws Exception

```
Exception in thread "stopThread" java.lang.RuntimeException : Unhandled and unknown native exception
at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.IContainer_open__SWIG_0( Native Method )
at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.open(IContainer.java:597 )
```

This is not the case as far as Windows concerns...
I am very much new for the Xuggler..I dont Know what this exception means..This is the line of code from where I got this exception.

```
if (container1.open( fileName, IContainer.Type.READ, container1.getContainerFormat()) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + fileName);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S : I Have used same version of the Java (1.7.0_65) and that of Oracle only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Solution..

I have changed my method of opening container.

Previous Method :

```
if (container1.open( fileName, IContainer.Type.READ, container1.getContainerFormat()) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + fileName);
        }
```

New Method :

```
InputStream inputStream = null ;
        try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("fileName"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            logger.error("File not found ");
        }

        IContainerFormat format = IContainerFormat.make();
        format.setInputFormat("flv");


        container1 = IContainer.make();


        if (container1.open( inputStream , format) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + fileName);
        }
```

And this works for the MAC OS..

Strange But True